Stream (download) a file from azure blob storage to user through flask
I wrote this piece of code that downloads a file from the azure storage account and then sends it to the user. However it has to first fully download the file and then send the file to the user. would it be possible to "stream" the file so that the download (on the user side) basically starts immediately and no file has to be saved on the server.
Before someone says to use the azure link with the SAR token, let me tell you tha I am not allowed to user SAR tokens.
@forecasting_bp.route("/api/download/", methods=["GET"])
def download():
    """"""
    report = request.args.get("report")
    config_id = request.args.get("config_id")
    extension = request.args.get("extension", ".csv")
    filename = f"{report}{config_id}{extension}"
    blobpath = f"{config_id}/{filename}"
    with open(filename, "wb") as my_blob:
        download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
        my_blob.write(download_stream.readall())
    return send_file(
        filename,
        as_attachment=True,
        download_name=filename,
    )


@DasariKamali what do you mean? the user is using the browser

I downloaded the CSV blob file from the Azure storage using the Flask app. Output at browser, VS code output.

I used the Azure storage connection string in the code, not the SAS token.

@DasariKamali, i don't think i follow, can you show me your code? what i would like to do is start sending the file to the user while i'm still downloading the file from azure

Here is my Github repo.

Thanks @DasariKamali i will try it, in stream_blob there's the argument chunk_size, but you're not using it, how are you supposed to use it?

I used chunk_size in the code, please check the above GitHub repo.

@DasariKamali sorry, but i really don't see it being used inside stream_blob, can you tell me the line number of its usage?

I updated my GitHub repository to include the chunk_size in the code. Please check it.

Can you able to download the blob with my updated GitHub repo?

@DasariKamali, yes i couldn't test it yet unfortunately, because my access to azure has been locked, i will try tomorrow

@DasariKamali it works wonderfully! thank you :), I would change your comment to answer but i don't know how to do it

I will provide it as an answer.

I converted my comments into an answer to help the community.
I tried the below code to download a file from Azure blob storage to the user through Flask. Here is my Github repo for complete code.
Code :
views.py :
import os
from flask import Blueprint, request, Response
from .azure_blob import get_blob_client

forecasting_bp = Blueprint('forecasting_bp', __name__)

def stream_blob(blob_client, chunk_size=1024*1024):
    """Generator function to stream the blob in chunks."""
    blob_size = blob_client.get_blob_properties().size
    start = 0

    while start < blob_size:
        end = min(start + chunk_size, blob_size)
        download_stream = blob_client.download_blob(offset=start, length=chunk_size)
        chunk = download_stream.readall()
        yield chunk
        start = end

@forecasting_bp.route("/api/download/", methods=["GET"])
def download():
    connection_string = os.getenv("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING")
    container_name = os.getenv("AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME")
    
    report = request.args.get("report")
    config_id = request.args.get("config_id")
    extension = request.args.get("extension", ".csv")
    filename = f"{report}{config_id}{extension}"
    blobpath = f"{config_id}/{filename}"

    blob_client = get_blob_client(connection_string, container_name)
    blob_client = blob_client.get_blob_client(blob=blobpath)

    response = Response(
        stream_blob(blob_client, chunk_size=1024*1024),
        content_type='application/octet-stream',
        headers={
            "Content-Disposition": f"attachment; filename={filename}"
        }
    )

    return response

.env :
AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING="<storage_conneString>"
AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME="<container_name>"

Output :

Browser output :
http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/download/?report=sample_report&config_id=123&extension=.csv


